# < select name="options" multiple > How to store in DB with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

How would I store `<option >`'s in a multiple select like so `<select name="options" multiple>` with my database i'm guessing something like json, but I'm unsure.

To then save it from my controller has

```
$options = Input::get('options');
```

How would one do this ?

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would have:

- a table containing your free form results
- a table containing all the options that can be selected from
- a junction table

The junction table would generally have two columns. Each would be a foreign key. One would match the id of the row in the first table. One would match the id of the second table. Together they would form a compound primary key.

See [wikipedia: Junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) for more details.

Comment: Fixed it by adding [] to my name value so name="options[]"


Then using json_encode
      $options = Input::get('options');
      $product->options = json_encode($options);

Comment: Adding `[]` to the name has nothing to do with the storage problem (it's an issue with passing the data to PHP). Storing the data as JSON is an awful idea. You have a relational database server. Use its relational features.

Comment: Because I'm using dropdown menu's so JSON was the easiest and quickest option.